# Partial correlation coefficient in terms of student's t

Tags: regression, self-study, t-test, econometrics, partial-correlation

I would like some help proving this expression of partial correlation in terms of student's t :

r(yx.efd.....p)² = t²/[t²+n-k-1]

Can you please direct me to a source explaining how to go about this? I just don't know how. I'm not a spammer or anything. This question was previously deleted, can I understand why?
Many thanks,

Edit : Since my previous question hasn't been answered, now I'm looking for sources or books to be able to answer it.

Comment: Please don't just repost [closed questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/608702/1352). Instead, edit them to address the reasons for closure, then they may well be reopened.

Comment: I just did answered your question on my original post. Many thanks